# What is the purpose of the Kafka Consumer "subscription" function?

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, librdkafka, rust-rdkafka

I am writing some test code to experiment with the Kafka Consumer `subscription()` function.

I don't understand what the intended purpose of this function is.

Here is a link to the [JavaDoc reference](https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscription()), which doesn't provide much helpful information.

Although I am writing the code in Rust, using Rust-rdkafka, the docs appear to be the same for Java, and of course the underlying C++ rdkafka implementation.

The function I am calling is this one:

```
let subscription = consumer.subscription().unwrap();
```

It returns this data:

```
element.topic: "kafka_test"
element.partition: -1
element.offset: Invalid
element.metadata: ""
element.topic: "kafka_test_1.json"
element.partition: -1
element.offset: Invalid
element.metadata: ""
```

What I don't understand is why it returns no offset, metadata or partition. I have tried calling `poll()` several times to get records back, and still the output of this is the same. I have also experimented with committing the current offset, but still the output is the same.

Poll returns data - so the topics are indeed created and they do have data on them.

Here's a little test code (not totally complete) to play with.

```
fn main() {

    // This is actually different each time the program is run
    let group_id = "test_group_id" + run_counter;

    let mut client_config = ClientConfig::new();
    let client_config = client_config
        .set("bootstrap.servers", ...)
        .set("security.protocol", ...)
        .set("sasl.mechanisms", ...)
        .set("sasl.username", ...)
        .set("sasl.password", ...)
        .set("group.id", group_id)
        .set("enable.auto.commit", "false")
        .set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        .set_log_level(rdkafka::config::RDKafkaLogLevel::Debug);

    let consumer: BaseConsumer = client_config
        .create()
        .expect("invalid producer config");
    
    consumer.subscribe(&topic_names).expect("consumer subscribe failed");

    test_function(&consumer, std::time::Duration::from_secs(30));
}


pub fn test_function(
    consumer: &BaseConsumer,
    poll_duration: Option<Duration>
)
{
    
    let something = consumer.poll(poll_duration);
    log::info!("something={:?}", something); // gets a valid record... (not "None")

    // Test subscription()
    let subscription = consumer.subscription().unwrap();

    // Print elements of topic map
    // As above, offset is invalid, partition is invalid ... why?
    let elements = subscription.elements();
    for element in elements.into_iter() {

        let topic = element.topic();
        let partition = element.partition();
        let offset = element.offset();
        let metadata = element.metadata();

        log::info!("element.topic: {:?}", topic);
        log::info!("element.partition: {:?}", partition);
        log::info!("element.offset: {:?}", offset);
        log::info!("element.metadata: {:?}", metadata);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two questions in one: "What is the purpose of the Kafka Consumer "subscription" function?" (easy, returns the topics you `subscribe`'ed to) and "why it returns no offset, metadata or partition" (harder, are the topics created? do they have any data in them?). Please clarify.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It would be quite a dumb question if the topics didn't have data on them - but I will update

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The question really is while, yes, it does return the names of the topics subscribed to - why does it have other data there if it appears to just be set to invalid? Is that intentional?

Comment: I suggest you create a github issue with the rust-rdkafka library developer to ask that

Answer (score 0):

It's not meant to get topic metadata, only the names of the topics assigned to the client (you can see Javadoc returns a collection of strings, not a topic object).

If you've defined one string, or static list in the subscribe function, it's not very useful, but if you use a regex pattern, it can help verify you're reading the correct data.

You'll need to use your `something` variable to get those values instead.

There's [example code](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/simple_consumer.rs#L73) that prints those values.

You can also use [`StreamConsumer`](https://docs.rs/rdkafka/0.33.2/rdkafka/consumer/stream_consumer/struct.StreamConsumer.html) rather than the lower level base one

Comment: That example doesn't seem relevant as it doesn't contain any calls to `subscription` ?

Comment: Because that's not how you get the data you're interested in? It's meant to only return the topic names, thus why everything else is a nil/default value

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - why would those fields be provided if they are always set to some invalid or null value?

Comment: As mentioned, you'll need to ask the developer of the library that question. If they were to follow the Java spec, it would only return a collection of strings

Comment: For reference, the Go librdkafka client extracts only the topic names from the C struct  https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/consumer.go#L757-L764